# Trouble with Div Hide/Show on mouse click

Tags: html, show-hide

I tried your script but it isn't working right. I have edited my code below to show exactly what I am working with. Thank you so much for being helpful.

Quazi

Hi,

I am very new to JQuery.

I am trying to get a div to **fade in** after a click event and then **hide** after click anywhere. I have three divs set up to do this with css set as display:none. The problem is that the script does not work in IE8 and only works in ff/safari if I double click or triple click the menubar links below.

I am using the following code to show/hide these divs on mouse click:

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/tr/xhtml1/dtd/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

body,
    html {
        margin:0;
        padding:0;
        color:black;
        background:black;
        color:black;
    }
    #logo {
        margin-top:1%;
        width:12%;
        margin-left:5%;
        padding:1%;
        border:2px solid #FF8c00;
    }
    #showsbanner {
        margin-top:1%;
        width:60%;
        position:absolute; 
        right:2px;
    }
    #wrap {
        width:90%;
        margin:0 auto;
        background:black;
        color:black;
    }
    #header {
        padding:5px 10px;
        background:black;
        color:#ef9c00;
    }
    h1 {
           color:#35002c; 
        font-family:"verdana";
        font-size:25px;
    }
    h2 {
           color:#044476; 
        font-family:"verdana";
        font-size:18px;
    }
    h3 {
           color:#044476; 
        font-family:"verdana";
        font-size:15px;
    }
    #nav {
        padding:5px 10px;
        width:89%;
        margin-left:5%;
        background:#ff8c00;
        border:2px solid darkblue;
    }
    #nav ul {
        margin:0;
        padding:0;
        list-style:none;
    }
    #nav li {
        display:inline;
        margin:0;
        padding:0;
        color:white;
    }

```
#menubar {
    float:left;
    width:40%;
    padding:1%;
    background:#ff8c00;
    margin-bottom:1%;
    border:2px solid darkblue;
}
#bcity {

    float:right;
    width:50%;
    padding:1%;
    background:#ff8c00;
    margin-bottom:1%;
    border:2px solid darkblue;
}        
#aicbk {
    display:none;
    float:right;
    width:50%;
    padding:1%;
    background:#ff8c00;
    margin-bottom:1%;    
    border:2px solid darkblue;
}
#pdil{
    display:none;
    float:right;
    width:50%;
    padding:1%;
    background:#ff8c00;
    margin-bottom:1%;
    border:2px solid darkblue;
}
#footer {
    clear:both;
    padding:1px, 1px;
    background:#ff8c00;
    width:100%;
    border:2px solid darkblue;
}
#footer p {
    color:white;
    font-size:12px
}
* html #footer {
    height:1px;
}
```

//The last four lines are an IE bug fix

```
</style>
```

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="homepage_files/js/jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>


<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    var gLastH = null;
    var gLastId = null;
    $('.toggleh').hide();

    $('.toggle').click(function(e) {
        $('.toggleh:visible').fadeOut('slow');
        gLastId = $(this).attr('id');
        console.log('#' + gLastId + 'h');
        gLastH = $('#' + gLastId + 'h');
        $(gLastH).fadeIn('slow');
        e.stopPropagation();
    });

    $('*').click(function(e) {
        if ($(this).attr('id') != gLastId) {
            $(gLastH).fadeOut('slow');
        }

        e.stopPropagation();
    });
});
</script>
```

stuff...





    


        
            text here
        


        
            text here2
        


        
            text here3
        

    






    


        

            stuff......

```
    <div class="toggleh" id="toggle2h">

            <div id="aicbk">
                stuff....



            </div>
    </div>


    <div class="toggleh" id="toggle3h">


            <div id="pdil">

                stuff..    

            </div>

    </div>







<div id="footer">

    stuff..

</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a working sample, tested under Chrome 8.0.552.0 dev:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>S.O. 3920865</title>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var gLastH = null;
        var gLastId = null;
        $('.toggleh').hide();

        $('.toggle').click(function(e) {
            $('.toggleh:visible').fadeOut('slow');
            gLastId = $(this).attr('id');
            console.log('#' + gLastId + 'h');
            gLastH = $('#' + gLastId + 'h');
            $(gLastH).fadeIn('slow');
            e.stopPropagation();
        });

        $('*').click(function(e) {
            if ($(this).attr('id') != gLastId) {
                $(gLastH).fadeOut('slow');
            }

            e.stopPropagation();
        });
    });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="menubar">
        <div class="toggle" id="toggle1">
            text here
        </div>
        <div class="toggleh" id="toggle1h">
            some description in here I suppose
        </div>

        <div class="toggle" id="toggle2">
            text here2
        </div>
        <div class="toggleh" id="toggle2h">
            some description in here I suppose 2
        </div>

        <div class="toggle" id="toggle3">
            text here3
        </div>
        <div class="toggleh" id="toggle3h">
            some description in here I suppose 3
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Perhaps you need to check [jQuery UI accordion](http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/) which can be what you really want.

**EDIT**: following 1st comment.

Comment: This is a super example RC! Thank you. It works perfectly of course. I just wonder if it is possible to script for three toggleh classes to load in a separate div box from the "toggle1", "toggle2" and "toggle3" . In other words can I have toggle1 click to open toggleh1 in a second div box, toggle2 click to open toggleh2 in the same second div box etc;?

Comment: The code is not working when I move the toggleh divs to another box.

Comment: <div id="menubar">
  
  
        <div class="toggle" id="toggle1">
            text here
        </div>
        

        <div class="toggle" id="toggle2">
            text here2
        </div>
        

        <div class="toggle" id="toggle3">
            text here3
        </div>
       
 </div>
then:

Comment: <div class="toggleh" id="toggle1h">
          
       
  <div id="bcity">
 
   stuff......
     
    </div>
     
   </center>
  </div>

   
  <br>
 </div> 
 
  <div class="toggleh" id="toggle2h">
       
    <div id="aicbk">
     stuff....
     
     
      
    </div>
  </div>
    
    
  <div class="toggleh" id="toggle3h">
            
       
    <div id="pdil">
   
     stuff.. 
      
    </div>
   
  </div>

Comment: Probably due to your CSS rules (`display:none;`)

Comment: Hi RC. Thanks. I removed the embarrassing display:none. lol. Still doesn't work though. Do you think the script can't identify toggleh when it is embedded in another div?

Comment: Nope, I think it's a css problem, try without any rule.

Answer (score 0):

Use this simple code to hide/show menu (or any div)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function toggle_visibility(id) {
   var e = document.getElementById(id);
   if(e.style.display == 'block')
      e.style.display = 'none';
   else
      e.style.display = 'block';
}
</script>

<a href="#" onclick="toggle_visibility('foo');toggle_visibility('foo2_too');">Click   here to toggle visibility of element #foo</a>
<div id="foo" style="display:block">This is foo</div>
```