# how to animate show a hidden div in jquery?

Tags: jquery

Dumb question but I can't seem to figure this out.

I have a div and hide it when the page loads like so

```
$("e").hide();
```

then when a user persons a specific action I want the div to animate or slide down gracefully. But on my site the animation just flashes and shoes the hidden div and no fade or `slideDown` effects occur.

I use

```
$("#e").hide();
$("#p").change(function() {
    if ($("#p").val() === 'Married') {
        $("#e").slideDown(500);
    } else {
        $("#e").slideUp(500);
    }
});
```

Comment: what is `$("#p")`? what element?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3920865/trouble-with-div-hide-show-on-mouse-click

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use `animate` to do the same thing [**animate**](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) like this.

```
$("#e").hide();
$("#p").change(function(){
    if($("#p").val() === 'Married'){
        $("#e").animate( { "opacity": "show", top:"100"} , 500 );
    }else{
        $("#e").animate( { "opacity": "show", top:"150"} , 5000 );
    }
});
```

to slide up and down you can play with height and width of div.

Comment: the div is embedded in the middle of 2 other Divs, I was wanting for the DIV to slide down pushing down the bottom DIV as it slidesDown

Comment: This works great, but If I might ask... Is there a way to make it "push" the DIV below it to as it fades into view?

Answer (score 10):

Instead of:

```
 {
    $("#e").slideDown(500);
 } else {
    $("#e").slideUp(500);
 }
```

Write this:

```
$("#e").toggle(500);
```

This will show  or hide your DIV.
It's 1 line solution.

Answer (score 5):

Use the `Toggle` function in order to do this.

```
$("#p").toggle(function(){
    // Your toggle code here
});
```

Comment: I can't seem to get why? why `.toggle()` on `$("#p")`?

Comment: This seems like the best way to do it

Answer (score 1):

You can use Animate [Animate](http://api.jquery.com/animate/)
simple example:

```
$("#p").animate({ opacity: 0 }, 600).prependTo($list);
```

where list is the parent

and it works fine with all browsers

Answer (score 1):

I realise this is now years old, but having arrived here looking for the same information, you can now use a duration which does the sliding animation for you. For example:

```
$("#p").change(function() {
  $("#e").toggle(500);
});
```

Lots more [options available](https://api.jquery.com/toggle/).

Answer (score -1):

Why not just `$("#e").fadeOut(250);` or something?

Comment: because the DIV is hidden from the user until a certain action is performed, if I fade it out it will have a quirky look when my form loads :-)